# SuperUser posting for FrameMaker

Tags: discussion

I have tried three times to contact, who I thought, was the mediator for the SuperUsers site and cannot seem to get a response. The following is what I wrote:

*DavidPostill - When I look at the first screen in SuperUser, I do not see my question. How do I get my question to show up so someone can comment?*

Comment: @Linda Lawson-Brunton people saw your question. It was seen 16 times as i am seeing but either people were not interested in your question or they didn't know the answer

Comment: Well thank you very much (no sarcasm) for at least getting back to me. I looked for it in SuperUser and in the main screen and couldn't find it. Therefore, my natural assumption is that it was not posted anywhere. If you can see it and there just is no answer (yet), that's fine. All I wanted was an answer and Ramhound got back to me (not David Postill) and was incredibly rude.  I was downvoted two times JUST FOR ASKING A QUESTION. It wasn't unti l posted here that I got any response at all.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Look at the last comment Ramhound made - STOP SPAMMING. I'm not spamming I am asking a question. To whom can I log a compalint about Ramhound? I asked a question - it wasn't answered - I asked it again - it wasn't answered (and, if you care to look, the original messages at a different symbol in front of the name because I didn't know if he was getting my messages or not) so I asked it in a general forum where Ramhound called me a spammer. He is rude and mean and I really want someone to know that AND he is blocking me from responding to my own post.

Comment: @Ramhound - you are the rudest person I have ever seen. I asked a simple question and didn't get a response. The first response I got was your rude response in SuperUser. Then you tell me to stop spamming? I am surprised you have anything to do with the SuperUser site since you obviously can't tell a question from a spam! I promote this site every single chance I get because I think it is a great resourse - but I will DEFINATELY tell folk to not go to SuperUser since he seems to randomly hate people!

Comment: Just so you know, your question would have appeared on the main page when it was migrated here on June 23. The site gets hundreds of questions per day, and new pages of questions are layered on as they arrive. Being on the main page isn't necessary, though.  Most of the active answerers follow the tags that they're interested in.  Your question is the only one with that tag, which suggests that there may not yet be an active group of users here with expertise.  It looks like it doesn't yet even have a dedicated Adobe community, but check their support link: https://helpx.adobe.com/support.html

Answer (score 6):

A good starting point for an answer would be the help and tour pages - you can find these on the top of the page. Read these.

You can't @ someone who hasn't replied to a post - a correct use of an @ would be when talking to multiple people on a comment thread.

As for getting your question on the front page - SU has a reasonable amount of volume and a lot of experienced users tend to use other means to find questions.

Should you have sufficient rep you could offer a bounty (but I wouldn't recommend it here). Otherwise the only thing to really do is to wait for an answer.

In addition, David Postill isn't a moderator. He's just a particularly active and helpful user. Once again, have a look at the help to see how the site works

Comment: I understand - but, are you really telling me that my question wasn't valid? 
About the @ thing, PLEASE look at my original question. You will see that I used @, #, and * because I didn't know if he was getting my messages AND because I was told my another mediator to ALWAYS use the @ so it gets to their (?) inbox. 
WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO TO GET EVERYONE TO UNDERSTAND THAT I DON'T CARE IF IT WAS ON THE FRONT PAGE. THAT WASN'T WHAT I ASKED! I simply asked why I could not see it AT ALL ON ANY PAGE.

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton you can see it if you look at the tag page for [tag:framemaker], so yes, it does exist on the site. Please stop yelling at people, and please take some time to read the [tour] and [help] so you can understand how the site works. How comment notification works is explained in the help center. Also, we're called moderators, not mediators, and the moderators all have a ♦ symbol after their username.

Comment: *Journeyman Geek So, I just want to clarify I DO NOT, AND DID NOT EXPECT, TO SEE MY POST ON THE FRONT PAGE. I NEVER ASKED FOR THAT AND I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS IS AN ISSUE. I didn't my post on ANY page either in SuperUser or in the main page.

Comment: @nhinkle - I get this site works - I have another FrameMaker question that has not been answered. However, the difference between my first FrameMaker question and my second FrameMaker question is that I could FIND the post for the first question. Does anyone understand this at all? My question yesterday was about using code in FrameMaker - how was that wrong. 
And, yelling? I suppose if people would stop being rude (Ramhound), and stop accusing me of asking for something that I didn't ask for (The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like) in an effort to make it look like he's right I wouldn't get upset.

Comment: @nhinkle - as for the Mediator/Moderator thing, you are completely right and I caught that after the fact but, you were right and I will make sure I do not make that mistake again.
Also, thank you for telling me about the diamond that shows up after the moderators name.

Comment: @nhinkle - this is a great site, wonderful resource for random information that cannot be found anywhere else. I've gotten lots of tips from StackExchange. As well, I have sung your praises and told a bunch of folk about this site. Since I am a tech writer in the San Jose, Ca. area AND  a contractor, I am in contact with many people from many industries. I always tell them how indispensable this site is and in return, I receive praise for telling folk about it as well.

Comment: @nhinkle - But, tell me how you can allow someone as unreasonable as Ramhound represent such a fantastic site? The comments were rude and uncalled for – and it's too bad he didn’t understand that I couldn’t see my post ANYWHERE on the site. I will continue to promote this site but, unless I get an apology from Ramhound, I will temper my enthusiasm with a disclaimer to stay away from SuperUser because a moderator named Ramhound will insult you for absolutely no reason and then call you a spammer if he doesn’t like your post.

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton first of all, thank you for telling people about Super User. I'm glad you've found it useful. Did you find the link to the framemaker tag which I gave you? Your questions should appear there. Most questions are not answered by people browsing the front page, they're answered by people browsing tags which are relevant to them. You can also always see your posted questions from [your own user profile](http://superuser.com/users/461836/linda-lawson-bruton?tab=questions).

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton - I just asked you not to repeat the same comment over and over.  How am I suppose to know you don't care what page your question is on, you seem specifically upset, it isn't one the first page based on the current question.  **I also didn't downvote your Framemaker question(s) just this question because it wasn't on topic at Superuser.  Your question is just a little over 24 hours old.  You might not get an answer at all, honestly, you are the sole person asking about Framemaker.

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton - I never insulted you..  I am also not a moderator, you couldn't pay me enough, to become a moderator at Superuser.  If you feel insulted I do apologize for that though

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton Second, please understand that Ramhound is not a moderator, he's just a regular - albeit very active - user. He does not officially represent the site in any way. I'm sorry you felt offended by his comments, but I don't think they were meant in bad faith. As he's explained here, he was simply calling you out for posting the same comment over and over again - behavior which we don't condone. You can always edit your comments within 5 minutes of posting them if you want to change; there's no need to repost them repeatedly.